# Find $F(1) = 0$, of the antiderivative $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{8}{x^{2}}-\frac{9}{x^{6}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the function $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{8}{x^{2}}-\frac{9}{x^{6}}$.

Let $F(x)$ be the antiderivative of $\,f(x)$ with $F(1) = 0$.

$$-\dfrac{8}{x}-\dfrac{9}{5x^5}$$

$$-\dfrac{8}{(1)^2}-\dfrac{9}{5(1)^5} + C = 0$$

$$\dfrac{8}{1}+\dfrac{9}{5} = C$$

$$ C = 9.8 $$

Then,

$$F(x) = -\dfrac{8}{x}-\dfrac{9}{5x^5} + 9.8$$

Why is this not correct?

Comment: Check the sign of the second term in the antiderivative.

Comment: As a helpful tip, you should read about how to ask good questions and how to format your work using MathJax. The longer you wait, the more flags and down-votes you'll receive. Furthermore, you should do more research about antidifferentiation; you should be able to find some explanation somewhere else.

Comment: I'm in a accelerated summer course so I don't have time to "research". This is the 10th Section I've learned in one sitting.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{8}{x^{2}}-\frac{9}{x^{6}} \\
&= 8x^{-2} - 9x^{-6} \\
F(x) &= -8x^{-1} + \frac{9}{5}x^{-5} + C \\
F(1) = 0 &= \frac{-8}{1} + \frac{9}{5(1)^5} + C \\
0 &= -\frac{31}{5} + C
\end{align}$$

You can take it from there.

A general tip for your first calculus class: make sure *every* line of work has an $=$ sign, and make sure that $=$ sign is actually meaningful.